# Is Iruma a descendant of the previous demon lord?

Tags: welcome-to-demon-school-iruma-kun

The previous Demon Lord Derkilla has been shown to have a very uncanny resemblance to Iruma, especially with regards to both their hair color and style. Is this just a coincidence? Because if Iruma were a descendant, then he would naturally be a demon, but rather he is a human.